# Compute average in Binary Search Tree C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, average

I'm stuck as to how to find the average value of integers in a binary search tree of integers.

If the tree is empty, it should return 0.

My code so far is:

```
//Node class
class Node
{
public:
private:
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
friend class BST;
};

Binary Search Tree class
class BST
{
public:
    Node* insert(int value, Node* root)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            root = new Node;
            root->data = value;
            root->left = root->right = NULL;
        }
        else if (value < root->data)
        {
            root->left = insert(value, root->left);
        }
        else if (value > root->data)
        {
            root->right = insert(value, root->right);
        }
        return root;
    }
    void insert(int x)
    {
        root = insert(x, root);
    }
    int sum(Node* root) {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return root->data + sum(root->right) + sum(root->left);
    }
    int count(Node* root)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return count(root->right) + count(root->left) + 1;
    }
    double average(Node* root) {
        return (double)sum(root) / count(root);
    }

private:
    Node* root;
};

int main()
{
    BST tree;
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(25);
    tree.insert(15);
    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(30);
    tree.insert(0);

    cout << tree.average(root) << endl; // this gives an error

}
```

I added some helper functions, but let me know if any of them is wrong too..

When I call average() function, it gives me an error. I think I need sum() function and count() function. And if count() is 0, then the average is 0. Then average() function will be just diving the sum by count.

Comment: What error do you get when you call `average`?

Comment: "identifier root is undefined"

Comment: Why is `average` taking an argument? It makes sense for `count`, and `sum`, because they are recursive, but `average` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your `average` function doesn't need a parameter at all. You could simply do:

```
double average() 
{
  return static_cast<double>(sum(root)) / count(root);  // uses the actual root
}
```

and call it like this:

```
cout << tree.average() << endl;
```

Comment: it seems that I still have an error. exited with code -1073741819.

Comment: That seems to be a run-time error. You'll need to debug your code to see where it crashes, and why.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is by having a wrapper function call a recursive function. The recursive function could have two variables which are passed by reference for the sum and amount. That way you only need to traverse once for both values.

Here is the wrapper function:

```
double average(node * root) {
    if(!root) {
        return 0; //base case if the tree is empty
    }

    int sum = 0; //variable for holding the sum
    int amount = 0; //variable for holding the amount of data

    averageRecursive(root, sum, amount); //calling the recursive function

    return (double)sum/amount;
}
```

And the recursive function that is being called:

```
void averageRecursive(node * root, int &sum, int &amount) {
    if(!root)
        return; //base case when we reach a node thats empty

    countAverage(root->left, sum, amount); //going to the left

    sum += root->data; //adding currents invocations root data to the sum
    ++amount; //adding one to the amount counter

    countAverage(root->right, sum, amount); //going to the right
}
```

You'd then call it from `main` with `tree.average()` and it will return the average.